# Reclassifying a Curvature raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, reclassify, curvature

I am trying to reclassify a profile curvature raster generated by the `Curvature` tool available in ArcGIS into three classes following the tool help where it is reported that;

> ...a negative value indicates the surface is upwardly convex at that
> cell. A positive profile indicates the surface is upwardly concave at
> that cell. A value of 0 indicates the surface is flat.

My Curvature raster' values range between -4.726 to 0.543. By supplying class breaks (-4.726, 0, 0.543) in the `Reclassify` tool yield spurious results where pixels having values == 0, as separately identified by raster calculator, are more in numbers (pixel count) than it should be!

What are optimal class break values to get accurate reclassified Curvature raster?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `Sign` function, which I don't think exists in the Raster Calculator.  Instead, you could nest `Con` functions, like this:

```
Con("ras"==0,0, Con("ras"<0,-1, 1))
```

From the help on the `Reclassify` tool, "the higher end of the lower input range is inclusive, and the lower end of the higher input range is exclusive."